# Show that Soc($\bigoplus_{\alpha\in I}M_\alpha$)=$\bigoplus_{\alpha\in I}\text{Soc}(M_\alpha)$

Tags: modules, socle

Given left $R$-modules $\{M_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in I}$ for some index set $I$, I'd like to show that the socle of their direct sum is the direct sum of each module's socle, that is, $$\text{Soc}(\bigoplus_{\alpha\in I}M_\alpha)=\bigoplus_{\alpha\in I}\text{Soc}(M_\alpha).$$

This isn't homework, just something I've come across while reading. I am just learning about modules, and I thought the proof would be easy, but I can't seem to work it out. Any help or guidance would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $socM:=$the direct sum of all simple submodules of $M$. Suppose that $M=M_1 \oplus M_2$, then it is easy to see that $soc(M_1) \oplus soc(M_2) \subseteq soc(M)$.

Now we check that $soc(M) \subseteq soc(M_1)\oplus soc(M_2)$: Let $\pi_i:M \rightarrow M_i$ be the canonical projection and $p_i: M_i \rightarrow M$ be the injection. Then we have that $1=p_1 \pi_1+p_2 \pi_2$. So $socM= p_1 \pi_1(socM)+p_2 \pi_2(socM)$. We also know that if $f: M \rightarrow N $ is a $R$-homomorphism, then $f(socM) \subseteq socN$. So $\pi_i(socM) \subseteq soc(M_i)$, then $soc(M)=p_1 \pi_1(socM)+ p_2 \pi_2(socM)\subseteq p_1(socM_1)+p_2(socM_2)=soc(M_1)\oplus soc(M_2)$.

And we can get the result similarly for any I.

Comment: It is not true that the simple submodules of a direct sum are contained in the summands. It already fails for vector spaces. Let k be a field, let M and N be 1-dimensional k-vector spaces: you should have no problem finding simple submodules of the direct sum of M and N which are not contained in either summand.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦ Thank you for your comment, you are right. And I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: Your edit also does not work: the intersections of the simple submodule with the two summands can very well be both zero! The exact same example I described earlier shows that this can happen.

Comment: (In fact, the only simple submodules of the direct sum for which one of the two intersections is nonzero are precisely the simple submodules which are contained in one of the two summands)

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez♦ Hello, sir. I have changed my answer. Is it right this time?